# Fetching entries by hours from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Unfortunately I am not very strong when it comes to SQL and not very strong when it comes to explaining myself. I will try my best and hopefully someone can help.

I have a table called soc_stat which has a lot of colums. One of those is "timestamp" which is just a timestamp, and the other one is a date_of_post which is just a `date_format();` of the timestamp, looking like this (example) 2015-08-28 00:18:52

What I would love to do it make a query that returns the amount of entries per day/hour

Something along the lines of this examples

```
2015-08-28 00:01:00 = 218 entries
2015-08-28 00:02:00 = 327 entries
2015-08-28 00:03:00 = 487 entries
2015-08-28 00:04:00 = 118 entries
```

I need it for a graph.

I currently use the following code to get the last 24 hours out from my database

```
SELECT * FROM `soc_stat` WHERE soc_stat.date_of_post > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

*Edit*

Thanks a lot for the answers. They worked exactly like how I wanted the information out. However I got one more question. As it is now if there is no inputs within an hour or day, there is not returned anything. Is is possible to get a 0 returned? I have a graph that depends on the values I get from the SQL query. So if I want a 24 hour graph some hours are not going to be displayed if there is no input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT date(t.date_of_post) AS date,
       hour(t.date_of_post) as hour,
       count(*) as entries
FROM `soc_stat` t
WHERE t.date_of_post > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY date(t.date_of_post), hour(t.date_of_post)
```

OR:

```
SELECT  DATE_ADD(date(t.date_of_post), INTERVAL hour(t.date_of_post)  HOUR)  AS dateTime,
       count(*) as entries
FROM `soc_stat` t
WHERE t.date_of_post > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY date(t.date_of_post), hour(t.date_of_post)
```

Comment: That is just perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I updated my question. Any chance you could assist me with the "edited" part? Would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

This is for per day and per hour

```
SELECT date(soc_stat.date_of_post) as date,hour(soc_stat.date_of_post) as hour,
count(*) FROM `soc_stat` 
WHERE soc_stat.date_of_post > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
group by date(soc_stat.date_of_post),hour(soc_stat.date_of_post)
```

Comment: I get the following error 

#1305 - FUNCTION breakingfeedstats.datepart does not exist.

I tried using datepart before with the same error. From what I've been able to read the datepart function is only used by Microsoft SQL Server and not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT date(t.date_of_post) AS date,
       hour(t.date_of_post) as hour,
       count(*) as entries
FROM `soc_stat` t
WHERE t.date_of_post > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY date(t.date_of_post), hour(t.date_of_post)
```